# Is there any way to make long texts in android have a behaviour like the photo below (Read more button)?

Tags: android, textview, longtext

[image]

is There any way in android to make some lines of the long text loose color ?

Comment: is textview's text is fixed or its dynamic and will keep changing?

Comment: There is no default way but you can definitely implement something like this easily with defining max lines in TextView dynamic.

Comment: easy way but not the best way to do it is , take a image which transparent and place it over text view at bottom. when user clicks on read more button then make its visibility to gone

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you all the hints which you need to come up with solution rather than writing a solution

I'm assuming that your text is dynamic in nature that means text length will vary.

First of all, you will have a `constant` defined in your class which provides max line count to show initially (along with read more) button

```
// here for example, you want to show 5 lines along with read more button
private static final int DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION_LINES_PORTRAIT = 5;
```

Now, as soon as you set your text, you check whether your text's line count is less than 5 or not. If it's less than 5 then you don't need to show `read more` button at all. If it's more than 5 then you would set `maxLines` of that `TextView` to your default lines. Also you'll make `read more` button visible

```
textView.setMaxLines(DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION_LINES_PORTRAIT);
readMorebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Now, you'll simply toggle `maxLines` to either `default` or `actual` line count whenever user presses on that button. Along with that make `readMoreButton` visibility `gone` to `visible` respectively.

Also it might be possible that `TextView` layout inflation takes time, so you might want to run a `runnable` on `post` of that `TextView` so that you're sure whenever you call `textivew..getLineCount();` then you'll get correct value.

Regarding that gradient on top of `button`, you may simply have that `button` along with `full width` view on top of it (which would have a gradient background) in a vertical `LinearLayout`.

I hope this helps.